# When I add an interval to a datetime, PHP seems to alter other datetime variables. Why?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I don't really know how to ask this.

I have the same date saved in two variables.
Then I add 100 days to the second variable.
But both seem to be altered. Why does that happens?

```
$begin = new DateTime("20180101");
$end = $begin;
$end = $end->add(new DateInterval('P100D'));

echo $begin->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>";
echo $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

result is:

> 2018-04-11
>
> 2018-04-11

but I expected:

> 2018-01-01
>
> 2018-04-11

Comment: [add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) modifies the object. It returns itself for chaining purposes, but you're not "getting a new date", you're getting the same date object, that has been bumped up by however long an interval you specified.

Comment: Oddly, when you create `$end`, it's really a pointer to `$begin`. You need to clone the object instead. I couldn't explain why it works this way, though.

Comment: @aynber why is that "oddly"? That is literally how variable assignment works.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because it doesn't work that way with simple variables. I haven't done a deep dive into objects to notice if it clones or references.

Comment: You actually don't need to go much further @aynber, this behaves exactly the same with, say: stdClass. If you create one object from it, set an attribute, equals another variable using it, and then change this attribute, it will do exactly the same.

Comment: @aynber it most certainly does. Primitives are copied by value, but everything else copies the reference. This is common and expected behaviour among procedural programming languages.

Comment: I... actually disagree that this is a duplicated question for the one mentioned. He never asked how to deep copy a DateTime object, he merely asked why the dates kept the same, which, even if answered in the referenced topic, is not what he asked.

Comment: There's also [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) to help prevent this from biting you, and `use \DateTimeImmutable as DateTime;` if you don't want to type "Immutable" more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have different days using the same DateTime object, you have to do this:

```
$begin = new DateTime("20180101");
$end = clone $begin;
$end = $end->add(new DateInterval('P100D'));

echo $begin->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>";
echo $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

And as of why: PHP is using the same object by reference...
If you create two different objects DateTime by new DateTime('pattern') it will behave perfectly ok.

The behaviour you are seeing now can be observed like this also:

```
$test = new stdClass();
$test->sample = "What!?";

$another = $test;
$another->sample = "Impossibru!";

echo $another->sample . "<br>";
echo $test->sample . "<br>";
```

Comment: Instead of cloning DateTime use [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) instead.

Comment: DateTimeImmutable is a very specific solution that can be used only in this kind of object, as of cloning works on every object...

Comment: This is a very specific question with a specific optimal solution :)

Comment: Well. If I can give a solution that will work on this and any other object. Why should I specify a solution only for this object?